# Impala query Result Storing into variable

Tags: linux

****I have impala query **var=`impala-shell --ssl -B --quiet -q " show tables in db_name**"` **and I want to store output of query into variable .I am able to store 
but it is store extra information which I want to remove by using Impala command line options .This is the extra information which I am getting in the result and want to remove****

> (Starting Impala Shell without Kerberos authentication SSL is enabled.
>   Impala server certificates will NOT be verified (set --ca_cert to
>   change) Error connecting: TTransportException, TSocket read 0 bytes
>   Kerberos ticket found in the credentials cache, retrying the
>   connection with a secure transport.

**

Note: [ I do not want to redirect to file ,I know it works ]

Comment: Try this var=${var%%(*}

Answer (score 0):

In my experience ,

you get the output of query in a variable as follows

```
var=$(impala-shell --ssl -B --quiet -q " show tables in db_name")
```

This should contain only the query output and not any other information such as

*"Starting Impala Shell without Kerberos authentication SSL is enabled....Fetched 1 rows in 1 sec.etc "*

In case you want this information also in a variable , you can do as follows

```
var=$(impala-shell --ssl -B --quiet -q " show tables in db_name" 2>&1)
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50857918/3840541 for more details